# in and for used with word register

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. selected to register **in** Maths course
> 2. selected to register **for** Maths course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'in' in th example of register in person, register in advance. But other than that for this case, register for a competition sounds better.